# Can't ignore folder with pckl files but can ignore all other folders

Tags: python, git, pickle, gitignore

I have a folder called dataset with pickle files to store my machine learning dataset. I also have two other folders with jpg files that store the actual images. My .gitignore file has

```
__pycache__/
train_images/
test_images/ 
dataset/
```

It worked perfectly for the train and test images, they are completely ignored. But the dataset folder isn't ignored and is available for commit. I have already tried deleting it and making a new folder but that doesn't work. This is my current git status

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   CNN.py
    modified:   data_prep.py
    modified:   dataset/num_train_labels.pckl
    modified:   dataset/test_images.pckl
    modified:   dataset/test_labels.pckl
    modified:   dataset/train_images.pckl
    modified:   dataset/train_labels.pckl
    modified:   image_scraping.py
    modified:   main.py
    deleted:    test_images/test_image1.jpg
    deleted:    test_images/test_image2.jpg
    deleted:    train_images/train_image1.jpg
    deleted:    train_images/train_image2.jpg

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Why does the dataset folder not get ignored?

Comment: Probably the files in there are already tracked (as in _they are part of HEAD_, already). If that's the case, you could delete them moving forward so that in later revisions git does not care for them: `git rm --cached some-files`

Comment: @eftshift0 when i used git rm --cached dataset/filename is said fatal: pathspec 'dataset/num_test_labels.pckl' did not match any files

Comment: Well.... I had told you that it was a _conditional_ solution. Can you paste the output of status in the question?

Comment: @eftshift0 oh crap I just realized u said status not git rm I just changed it

Comment: @eftshift0 also, i can't delete those files because they are greater than 100mb

Comment: Well, I don't know why git is complaining when you asked to delete the file you said. Can you run that rm command and paste the command and the output as part of the question as well? And sure, it's not working (ignoring them, that is) because the files are already tracked.

Comment: I was in the wrong repo when I used rm, it worked when I changed back to the original repo. I don't want to remove because git won't let me commit a file larger than 100mb

Comment: So what you would like is for those files (that are tracked) to avoid git from telling you that they are modified, do I get it right? If that's the case, try with `git update-index --assume-unchanged the-file`. That's a local-repo thing so if other developers want to do the same, they will have to run it on their repos as well.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks a lot! It worked. Is there any reason the .gitignore doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Thanks to eftshift0. I had to use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged filename
```

I still don't know why the .gitignore doesn't work though.

Comment: .gitignore only works for **untracked** files. Given that git is already tracking those, well.... you know.